# Returning a float from an Iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is a coding assignment for the class. I figured out how to make it work generically without being implemented into classes and functions. But when I start implementing it into classes and functions it gets little trickier and starts giving me troubles. The only problem I am currently having is returning the decimal value. Essentially my teacher wants the program to be able to return these decimal place values where the user input decides how many 0's there are.

i.e.

```
1 -> .1, .2, .3, .4, ...

2 -> .01, .02, .03, .04, ...

3 -> .001, .002, .003, .004 ...
```

Any help and possible questions being answered would be great! Thanks so much beforehand.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
__author__ = 'Garrett Sacken'

decimalLength = int(input("Enter the amount of decimal places you would like:"))

class DecimalGenerator:
    def __init__(self, userInput):
        self.userInput = userInput

    def __iter__(self):
        self.answer = 1.0
        return iter(self.answer)

    def __next__(self):
        count = 0
        divisor = 1
        for testNumber in range(1, 9):
            while count < self.userInput:
                divisor *= 10
                count += 1
            testNumber += 1
            self.answer = testNumber // divisor
            return self.answer
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use string formatting for this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by string formatting? Like instead of inputting numerical values input strings?

Comment: not input, but constructing those as output strings.

Comment: My teacher wants them to be input as Integers and returned as Floats

Comment: That was incidental to the main question - just an alternative way to construct he formatted output - see https://pyformat.info. (you'd need to switch to and from strings to use this of course).

Comment: What do you expect `iter(self.answer)` to return? You always set `self.answer` to `1.0` here.

Comment: I only set it to 1 because it was having a problem in the code about being declared. Then when I was trying to return self.answer it said it could not return float as it was not an iterator. So I did some researching and tried that return iter(self.answer) and it has only returned 0s so far.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the main issue here is that you don't understand how `__iter__` and `__next__` work. Answering this question would require 1) a complete rewrite of your code and 2) a complete explanation of generators (and specifically `__iter__` and `__next__`). (1) means we'd be doing your homework for you, and (2) means we'd have to repeat something that's already been explained countless times. Maybe somebody's willing to do all of that for you, but in any case I'd recommend you re-read the documentation about generators,`__iter__` and `__next__`.

Comment: Alright. For the most part I missed the lecture on Iterators and Generators due to being sick. I apologize if you thought my intentions on this post was an attempt to get my homework done for me by someone else. I shall go read up and try to understand how __iter__ and __next__ work. Thank so much anyways.

Comment: I do think you made an honest attempt to solve the assignment on your own, but there is a huge difference between doing this with a loop and doing it with a generator. You can't just paste your working code into the `__next__` method and expect it to do the right thing; that's not how generators work. So a lot of your code needs to change, and if we do that for you then we've essentially done the whole assignment for you.

Comment: Alright I’ll figure it out eventually! Thanks so much again!

Comment: @Aran-Fey not to mention, *this isn't a generator*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Let's not be nitpicky :P (The OP correctly said "iterator" anyway.)

Comment: @Aran_Fey well on the bright side I managed to get it to work. Just not sure how efficient I made the code haha